# Mixing multiple LDAP URL's with ldap connection pooling

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap

Im currently feeding a list of LDAP URL's to my spring security configuration -

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="adAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="adAuthenticationProvider"
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="mydomain" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldaps://dc1:636 ldaps://dc2:636 ldaps://dc3:636" />
    <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="contextSource"
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldaps://dc1:636/dc= ldaps://dc2:636/dc= ldaps://dc3:636/dc=" />
    <beans:property name="userDn" value="userdn" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
</beans:bean>
```

My understanding is that the Spring security LDAP configuration will loop through my list of domain controllers/ldap servers - until it finds one that is available

My question is can I implement a LDAP connection pool on top of this configuration?